# Simplify boolean expression $AB + A\bar B+ ABC $

Tags: boolean-algebra

> Simplify $AB + A\bar B+ ABC $

I've been trying to simplify for a good while now. I'm using only the 10 rules but cannot find a way to simplify fully.

Comment: So $(AB)' = \overline{AB}$ which means the complement of $AB$? What does + mean here? xor?

Comment: Sorry i posted the wrong question. Check below comment or updated version.

Comment: I think it is xor. The assignment is just says Simplify, using the laws of Boolean algebra: AB + AB̅+ ABC

Comment: What are your 10 laws that you are allowed to use? reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$AB + A\overline{B} + ABC = A(B + \overline{B}) + ABC = A + ABC = A(1 + BC) = A\overline{BC}$

Comment: Can't you simply replace $1+BC$ with $1$ (so that the final result is $A$)?

Comment: Not if + means xor, which was my assumption. Then $1+X$ is 0 if $X$ is 1, and vice versa. So $1+X = \overline{X}$.

Comment: Yeah, I just read the comments to the question. Since when is "$+$" = XOR? I'd expect it to be OR.

Comment: It's common in Boolean functions.

Comment: Isn't that the plus with a circle around it?

Comment: You can see BA as having basic operations $\lor,\land,\lnot$ or $+,\cdot,'$ axiomatically. Boolean rings etc. A Boolean ring is just a commutative unitary ring $R$ with $x + x = 0$ for all $x$. A BA is then defined by $\lnot x = 1 + x$, $x \lor y = x + y + xy$, $x \land y = xy$. It's a common different view. Yes, sometimes $x \oplus y$ is also used, in CS contexts.

Comment: I have done the translate in Italian language and your last answer it is perfect!